# MDX Query IIF vs CASE Performance

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

I have this MDX syntax which is not efficient when sliced using multiple dimension attributes. How can i improve the performance? what best to choose here IIF or CASE?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[test] AS 
    IIF
    (
      IsLeaf([Date].[MonthQtrYr].CurrentMember) = True
     ,IIF
      (
        [Measures].[1 Headcount] > 0 AND [Measures].[1 Termcount] > 0
       ,
        [Measures].[1 Termcount] / [Measures].[1 Headcount]
       ,null
      )
     ,IIF
      (
                [Date].[MonthQtrYr].CurrentMember IS [Date].[MonthQtrYr].[All]
              AND 
                [Date].[Month].CurrentMember IS [Date].[Month].[All]
            AND 
              [Date].[Quarter].CurrentMember IS [Date].[Quarter].[All]
          AND 
            [Date].[Week].CurrentMember IS [Date].[Week].[All]
        AND 
          [Date].[WeekbyYr].CurrentMember IS [Date].[WeekbyYr].[All]
       ,IIF
        (
          [Measures].[1 Headcount] > 0 AND [Measures].[1 Termcount] > 0
         ,
            [Measures].[1 Termcount]
          / 
            IIF
            (
              [TRegrets].[Regrets].CurrentMember IS [TRegrets].[Regrets].&[With Regrets]
             ,(
                [TRegrets].[Regrets].&[Not Applicable]
               ,[Measures].[1 Headcount]
              )
             ,[Measures].[1 Headcount]
            )
         ,null
        )
       ,IIF
        (
              [Date].[MonthQtrYr].CurrentMember
            IS 
              StrToMember
              (
                "[Date].[MonthQtrYr].[Year].&[" + Cstr([Measures].[MaxYear]) + "]"
              )
          OR 
              [Date].[Quarter].CurrentMember
            IS 
              StrToMember
              ("[Date].[Quarter].&["
                  + 
                    StrToMember
                    (
                      "[Date].[Quarter].&[Q" + Cstr([Measures].[PrevQtr]) + "]"
                    ).NextMember.Member_Caption
                + "]"
              )
         ,StrToMember("[Date].[Month].&[" + Cstr([Measures].[CurrMo]) + "]")
         ,[Date].[MonthQtrYr].CurrentMember.LastChild
        )
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to **whytheq** answer:

1. Looks like most of checks are connected with determining current level or specific calculations for some members.
   Therefore, try to use SCOPE.

E.g.

```
SCOPE ([Date].[MonthQtrYr].[<LeafLevelName>].Members,[Measures].[test]);
THIS = <calculation #1>;
END SCOPE;

SCOPE ([TRegrets].[Regrets].&[With Regrets],[Measures].[test]);
THIS = ([TRegrets].[Regrets].&[Not Applicable],[Measures].[1 Headcount]);
END SCOPE;
```

2. Please also try not to use late-bindings like `StrToMember()`. They switch server to slow cell-by-cell mode.

To calculate `previous quarter, current month, max year` try to use MDX functions: `Lag, Lead, ParallelPeriod, Parent, LastChild` etc.

3. Use calculated measure for repeating condition `[Measures].[1 Headcount] > 0 AND [Measures].[1 Termcount] > 0`, and use this measure further in calculations.

I understand it could be very hard, but the main goal is to let server operate with things it likes: **sparse sets of data**. Instead of tricky calculations.

**UPDATE:** (examples of calculations instead of `StrToMember`)

Not sure I understood calculations correct, since you didn't mention them in provided code. But here are some thoughts about.

Example of `Year > Quarter > Month > Day` hierarchy for `Report Date` dimension:

**Max Year** is calculated as year with maximum of `Count` measure (unfiltered result in comment) :

[image: AvoidStrToMember_1MaxYear]

Next is for **Current Month** (with YYYYMM key) if you need exactly this month w/o dynamics:

[image: AvoidStrToMember_2CurrMo]

For dynamic calculation `PrevMember` or `ParallelPeriod` could be used.

I haven't got the general idea of `[Measures].[PrevQtr]` usage. Looks like it's current quarter, isn't it?

If you provide more details about every calculation used for this measure, we can try to create faster code.

Comment: Thanks Alex...will try using the scope. How can i achieve the same that StrToMember() does without using it  
For EX:
StrToMember
            (
              "[Date].[Month].&[" + Cstr([Measures].[CurrMo]) + "]"
             ,Constrained
            )

Comment: (upped) I agree with all your suggestions Alex. I suspect that the measures such as `[Measures].[PrevQtr]` can be deleted and custom members created within the [Date] dimension

Comment: @Naveej, I've updated an answer, but we need more details.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

`IIF` is pretty much always quicker than `CASE` in `mdx`

`IIF` with `NULL` as one of its branches is fast.

`DIVIDE` could well be quicker than the operator `/`

Your measure is complex - would you expect it to run quickly?

Can you decompose it into several measures?

Comment: Agreed. The most significant improvement is possible after decomposing complex measure. Because of memory consumption and caching intermediate result.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. yes i can decompose but not sure as i might need to check on the conditions again isn't it..?

Comment: @Naveej do you have future dates in your cube's date dimension or is the last date in your date dimension today? In our cube it is the latter.